# javascript call after dataGrid pagination

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsf, primefaces

Is there a way to call a JS or jQuery function afterwards a PrimeFaces dataGrid has switched between pages and the data content has changed? I have to set a jQuery function for items that are shown on a data grid, since the items are shown page by page, i have to re-attach this jQuery function to the new items that are shown. Have tried the following with no success;

```
//way #1 - call ajax on complete/ on success after a page link has been clicked
$('.ui-paginator').click(function(e) {
                alert("enter");
                $.ajax({
                    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                        alert("success");
                        $('.certain-class').attachFunction();
                    },
                    complete: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                        alert("complete");
                        $('.certain-class').attachFunction();
                    }
                });
```

---

```
//way #2 - after the content of the data grid has changed, call the function 

$('.ui-datagrid-content').ajaxComplete(function() {
   alert("changed outside");
   $('.certain-class').attachFunction();
});
```

The result I'm getting is that the alerts are beeing called (so, the function is attached) but always before the content on the dataGrid is changed, I thought of using a timeout, but this is not the desired approach.

I'm using PF 5.0 .

Comment: PrimeFaces doesn't use jQuery ajax, so your approach won't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an ajax page event:

```
<p:dataGrid>
   <p:ajax event="page" onstart="alert("ajax started");"
                        onsuccess="alert("ajax success");"
                        oncomplete="alert("ajax completed");" />
</p:dataGrid>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! this indeed helped, didn't knew there was a "page" event on PF ajax.